# How to get fastri working with bundler driven projects

Tags: ruby, search, bundler, rdoc

I'd like to get the fastri engine working with bundler driven projects. Anybody know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to get bundler to stop using --no-ri --no-rdoc:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/383

Assuming you could get bundler to install the docs, your next problem is to point fastri to the GEM_PATH that bundler installed to.  But you're a long way from that concern. :-(